# Catching multiple exceptions in console app using one try{...}catch{...} block

Tags: c#, exception, console

I would like ask you to explain me how the exception system works in the following piece of code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            //Code which throws exceptions from time to time and runs in a loop
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

I noticed something which surprised me. When an exception is thrown, the code inside try{...} block is still running and can throw even more exceptions which will be printed to the console window.
Shouldn't the code inside the loop finish its execution and "jump" to Console.ReadKey() at the end?

@EDIT:

The code inside is complicated and it would take a few pages. I can tell you that I make multiple asynchronous operations inside like downloading files, receiving packets, etc. In other words there are other threads which are created in the loop.

@EDIT2:
Presumably this is the code responsible for the behavior:

```
public SomeConstructor(Socket server)
    {
        _pb = new PacketBuilder(server, c);

        SocketWrapper sw = new SocketWrapper(server, Globals.recvBufferSize);
        sw.Socket.BeginReceive(sw.Buffer, 0, Globals.recvBufferSize, SocketFlags.None,PacketReceiveCallback, sw);

        _pi = new PacketInterpreter(this, c);
    }

    private void PacketReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult iar)
    {
        SocketWrapper sw = iar.AsyncState as SocketWrapper;
        int bytesReceived = sw.Socket.EndReceive(iar);

        _pi.Interpret(sw.Buffer, 0, bytesReceived);

        if (bytesReceived > 0)
            sw.Socket.BeginReceive(sw.Buffer, 0, Globals.recvBufferSize, SocketFlags.None, PacketReceiveCallback, sw);
    }
```

Comment: There is no loop in your code. And unless you have an inner `catch` it will exit the try close on exception and never go back to it.

Comment: Yes it should. And you should provide the code inside the try{...} block for us to have any idea why it doesn't do that.

Comment: You probably shouldn't have a try block that contains so much code it requires a comment to save us having the difficulty of understanding it!

Comment: @Grakodile which part you don't understand? The code runs in a infinite loop and can throw infinite amounts of exceptions which will be displayed on screen. The question is how?

Answer (score 1):

Code inside try block will execute as long as it doesn't throw an exception. If the exception throw within your try block the following code will not execute and it will jump to catch block.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        //Code which throws exceptions from time to time and runs in a loop
        Console.WriteLine("Line 1");

        throw new Exception("Sample Exception"); // your code will stop here and following line will not prine.
        Console.WriteLine("This line will not print");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I can think of why you would get such a behavior is if you're starting new threads inside your try block. So if you're starting any new threads or using the task parallell library or plinq, you might get something like that.

But it's really hard to inspection-debug code that was replaced by a comment...